# Google Sheets comma in formula number and script number literals?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In other programming languages such as Java you can use _ in numbers to indicate commas for visualizing/comment purposes only such as 1_000 instead of 1,000:

1) Is there any equivalent in google sheets when working with hard coded large numbers in the actual formula? (in the spreadsheet itself) 2) Is there an equivalent in Google App Scripts? (in the app script editor)

Comment: There are no built-in numeric separators in JavaScript or in Google Sheets formulas. You can set custom formatting for display values (e.g. ###__###__###) but this won't carry over to formulas

Comment: @AntonDementiev that is a shame, maybe there is a hidden character that will work sort of how backticks can be used instead of double quotes.

Comment: GAS is built in JavaScript and, as far as I know, JavaScript doesn't have the same mechanism for number literals. The best I can think of would be an over-complication: reference numbers as strings and pass them to a function that strips the comma/underscore and returns a number. `function(n){ return parseInt(n.replace(/[^0-9]/, "")); }`.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript latest versions you can use `1_000` and it works nicely:

```js
var literal = 1_000_000;
console.log(literal);
```

But this can't be done on the current versions of Sheets or Apps Script:

**Around Apps Script:**

AppsScript uses an old runtime version of JavaScript on where this is unsupported, I believe it won't be long till AppsScript supports ES2017, it's on the roadmap but as now, it has no due date:

https://support.google.com/a/table/7539891?hl=en

**Around Google Sheets:**

I believe it should have this functionality, so if you send a Feature Request it may help to push its implementation, on here you can do it:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en